# Terminology for a generic type with type parameter filled in

Tags: generics, kotlin, terminology

What is the correct terminology for a generic type with type parameter filled in? It's a very common construct; I'm surprised to realize I'm not sure exactly what it should be called.

Put another way:

If `square` is a *function*, then `square(2)` is a *function call*.

If `List` is a *generic type*, then `List<Int>` is a...?

(I'm working in Kotlin if it matters, though it seems to me the terminology should probably be the same for many languages that support generics.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, `std::vector<int>` would be a **specialization** of `std::vector<T>`, and `std::array<int, N>` would be a **partial specialization** of `std::array<T, N>`.

These are templates, however.  As jaco0646 mentions, languages that use generics (such as Java and Rust) usually call them **parameterized**.

The closest equivalent in Haskell is typeclasses, and it (sometimes) calls the equivalent of parameterized generic code an **instance**.  (In object-oriented languages, an instance refers to an object of a class, but Haskell does not have classes, so there is no ambiguity.)

Answer (score 5):

In Java,

- `List<T>` is a [Generic Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).
- `List` is a [Raw Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).
- `List<Integer>` is a [Parameterized Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html#instantiation).

All types that support parameters are Generic Types.

> When coding, one provides type arguments in order to create a parameterized type.

If no type arguments are provided, a raw type is created instead.